# Cannot get OpenManage omreport for Dell running CentOS 7

Tags: dell, centos7, dell-openmanage

I'm trying to get `omreport` on a Dell R710 running CentOS 7, but failing.  The instructions at

http://linux.dell.com/repo/hardware/omsa.html

include a case for CentOS.  They involve using `wget` to set up a yum repo configuration for Dell OpenManage Repository, but the command

```
yum install srvadmin-all
```

produces

```
Loaded plugins: dellsysid, fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.unl.edu
 * extras: mirror.hmc.edu
 * rpmforge: mirror.hmc.edu
 * updates: mirrors.unifiedlayer.com
No package srvadmin-all available
```

The same thing happens with package `srvadmin-base`.  I checked the Dell OMSA FAQ, tried `yum clean all`, but still, no joy.  My `yum.conf` has `plugins=1`. In fact, here is my `yum.conf` file:

```
[main]
cachedir=/var/cache/yum/$basearch/$releasever
keepcache=0
debuglevel=2
logfile=/var/log/yum.log
exactarch=1
obsoletes=1
gpgcheck=1
plugins=1
installonly_limit=5
bugtracker_url=http://bugs.centos.org/set_project.php?project_id=23&ref=http://bugs.centos.org/bug_report_page.php?category=yum
distroverpkg=centos-release
```

And here is the output of `yum repolist`:

```
# yum repolist
Loaded plugins: dellsysid, fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.unl.edu
 * extras: mirror.hmc.edu
 * rpmforge: mirror.hmc.edu
 * updates: mirrors.unifiedlayer.com
repo id                                           repo name                                                   status
base/7/x86_64                                     CentOS-7 - Base                                              8465
dell-omsa-indep/7/x86_64                          Dell OMSA repository - Hardware independent                  2812
dell-omsa-specific/7/x86_64                       Dell OMSA repository - Hardware specific                     2812
dsu_repository_dependent/7/x86_64                 dsu_repository_dependent                                        0
dsu_repository_independent                        dsu_repository_independent                                  488+1
extras/7/x86_64                                   CentOS-7 - Extras                                             104
rpmforge                                          RHEL 7 - RPMforge.net - dag                                   245
updates/7/x86_64                                  CentOS-7 - Updates                                           1721
repolist: 16647
```

The Dell pages do not mention CentOS higher than 5, so is the problem that the Dell repository materials are not compatible with the latest CentOS?

In any case, how can I get `omreport` for CentOS 7?

Comment: Do you have `plugins=1` in yum.conf? Also post the output of `yum repolist` to see if you have the proper repos.

Comment: Yum, `plugins=1`.  I'll update my question to mention this and the output of `yum repolist`.  Thanks for your input.

Comment: Seems Centos 7 is not supported by OMSA, a workaround is described in this topic: https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=48532

Answer (score 4, accepted):

mhucka, Dell does not support OMSA on RHEL/Centos 7 unless you are on a 13th-generation server.  The R710 is an 11th-generation server.  I have a 12G server, and I'm reading that Dell may release support for that in OMSA 7.4.1 but that is still nowhere to be found, and I have not heard anything about 11G support.

You can always try forcing it to install, using the instructions here: 
https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=49&t=48532

Answer (score 1):

Just to add that I manage to install OMSA on RHEL(Citrix Xen Server 6.5) on a DELL R510 without too much trouble by simply pointing to the 'old' repository:

```
wget -q -O - http://linux.dell.com/repo/hardware/OMSA_7.4.0/bootstrap.cgi | bash
```

and then install srvadmin-all

```
yum install srvadmin-all
```